# webscraping python not showing all tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to webscraping. I was trying to make a script that gets data from a balance sheet (here the site: https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000010/a10-qq1202012282019.htm). The problem is getting the data: when I watch at the source code in my browser, I'm able to find the tag and the correct value. Once I write down a script with bs4, I don't get anything.

I'm trying to get informations form the balance sheet: Products, Services, Cost of sales... and the data contained in the table 1. (I'm sorry, but I can't post the image. Anyway is the first table you see scrolling down).

Here's my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = "https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000010/a10-qq1202012282019.htm"

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
read_data = urlopen(req).read()
soup_data = BeautifulSoup(read_data,"lxml")

names = soup_data.find_all("td")
for name in names:
    print(name)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you please specify what are you trying to find from URL!

Comment: can you check intermediary results/are you really able to get the expected html?

Comment: You should also mention what you are looking for clearly

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I need all data contained in the balance sheet (Financial statements, table 1). I also modified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this URL:

Also include the `headers` to get the data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000010/a10-qq1202012282019.htm"
headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup_data = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
```

You will be able to find the data you need.

Comment: It should work, but it gave me error 403 - forbidden access. So, I should check something different. Thanks anyway

Comment: I have updated the answer. You need to add headers to the request to avoid 403. Please check.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot!!! Could you explain me what was my error? Why deleting `ix?doc=` from the url makes the page static?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It is just that the URL you are using fetches the data from the URL I have posted which loads a static page.